# Dynamically set current_object and avoid using before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Suppose we have a **rails API**. In many controllers methods I need to set my current_object thanks to params from the request. I can then set a **before_action** like:

```
def set_current_object
  if My_object.exists? params[:id]
    @current_object = My_object.find params[:id]
  else
    render json: {error: 'Object not found'}.to_json, status:404
  end
end
```

This is ok. But I would like to **set current_object dynamically** in my controllers methods. Imagine I have a show method in one controller where I need to use my current_object like:

```
def show
  render json: {object_name: current_object.name}.to_json, status: 200
end
```

current_object would be a helper method like:

```
def current_object
  if My_object.exists? params[:id]
    return My_object.find params[:id]
  else
    render json: {error: 'Object not found'}.to_json, status:404
  end
end
```

Then, **if My_object.exists? params[:id] is false I would like to send a 404 and to stop my controller method**. Like written here, it is obviously not working. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. Typically you would implement this sort of "lazy-loading" as a method which [memoizes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) its return value using the [`||=` idiom](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/07/28/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/).

You simply need to modify your `current_object` helper so that it can trigger a 404 error when it's unable to return a valid value. Typically you would do this by raising a recognizable exception such as an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, and handling this in your controller with a `rescue_from` clause.

```
class ApplicationController
  def current_object
    if My_object.exists? params[:id]
      # memozie the value so subsequent calls don't hit the database
      @current_object ||= My_object.find params[:id]
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  
    end
  end


  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with: :show_404

  def show_404
    render json: {error: 'Object not found'}.to_json, status:404
  end
end
```

Now, because you're following a pretty standard Rails convention of handling `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` at the top-level of your controller hierarchy, you can now clean up your `current_object` method considerably. Instead of checking for the presence of a record, just try to find the record by id. If it doesn't exist, ActiveRecord will automatically raise the exception for you. In fact, your entire `current_object` method should be a single line of code:

```
class ApplicationController
  def current_object
    @current_object ||= My_object.find(params[:id])
  end

  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with: :show_404

  def show_404
    render json: {error: 'Object not found'}.to_json, status:404
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `My_object` is a model, if you simply use `find`, then a `params[:id]` that doesn't exist in the database will raise an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error, and Rails' `ActionController::Base` will catch the exception and render a 404 by default:

```
def current_object
  My_object.find params[:id]
end
```